# Why does the insertchart function not work in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling

Hello I use the code below and get the following error: **Exception: Service error: Tables (line 6, file "Macros")** 
Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

```
function AuswertungTest2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet1");
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify().setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0).build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chart); 
};
```

Comment: It is an internal error, I'm unable to reproduce your issue, I've tried this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("my_spreadsheet");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new spreadsheet1");
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify().setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0).build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Comment: And it works as intended. May the problem be on your spreadsheet? 
Try to run the same code on another spreadsheet, it should work, and please, tell us which is line 6 on your code.

Comment: line 6 is the insert chart function

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'modify' of undefined (Zeile 26, Datei "Makros") This error occures with ur code.

Comment: This error appears when you try to modify a chart that does not exist. So, this means that you are not getting any chart from the origin spreadsheet and thus it's failing on building it cause there is none.

Comment: But there clearly is a chart (diagram) on that spreadsheet, that is why it makes no sense

Comment: In order to debug this properly could you please provide a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet to be able to reproduce this error? Otherwise I can not do much more.